# Change the path included in a file with sed command in bash script

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to replace the path line of a file (test.txt) using bash script.
The path included in test.txt file is something like this:

```
setwd("/media/data/myfolder")
```

And my bash script is:

```
WORKDIR=$(dirname $(readlink -e $0))
mkdir -p "$WORKDIR/R_results"
outdir="$WORKDIR/R_results"
sed -e 's/^setwd.*/setwd("$outdir")/g' test.txt > test2.txt
```

When I run it, my ouput is:

```
setwd("$outdir")
```

I have tried several combinations with double and single quotes but I can't find the correct way. I hope I've made myself clear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the replacement path contains slashes, `sed` is confused about where the `s///` command starts and stops.  Use a different character, such as `%` or <kbd>Control-A</kbd>. You also need to use double quotes around the script since you want shell variables to be expanded in it.

```
WORKDIR=$(dirname $(readlink -e $0))
mkdir -p "$WORKDIR/R_results"
outdir="$WORKDIR/R_results"
sed -e "s%^setwd.*%setwd(\"$outdir\")%g" test.txt > test2.txt
```

(Using `%` — or <kbd>Control-A</kbd> come to that — assumes that the chosen character won't appear in your file name.)

Answer (score 1):

Variables are also not expanded inside single quotes, so you need to change your `sed` to

```
sed -e "s,^setwd.*,setwd($outdir),g" test.txt > test2.txt
```

Note, this will fail if $outdir contains commas.

Comment: If I do:
echo "$outdir"
/media/R_results
This is the path that I want to put inside test.txt file, (replacing /media/data/myfolder). If I run sed -e "s/^setwd.*/setwd($outdir)/g" , I get setwd() as an output.
Any other suggestion?

Comment: @user3481031 Odd, can't think of a case that would cause this

Comment: Ok, sorry, my fault. When I run your command, I get the following error:

sed: -e expression #1, char 21: unknown option to `s

And of course the path in the ouput file is not changed.

Comment: if double quote around your file are mandatory `sed -e "s/^setwd.*/setwd(\"$outdir\")/g"` like the source.

Comment: Still having the same error: sed: -e expression #1, char 21: unknown option to `s'

I think that is something related to the "/" included in the path..

Comment: @BroSlow The problem is that I have "/" in my $outdir variable. Because if I remove it, it works perfectly. But the fact is that I need those "/" to have the path obviusly...

Comment: @BroSlow OK the problem is solved. The correct way to do this is the following:
sed "s|$OLDPATH|$NEWPATH|g" oldfile >newfile
  Thanks for your answers anyway :)

Comment: @user3481031 That has the same issue as with a `,`. You can do s'char'$OLDPATH'char'$NEWPATH'char'g, but if the variables contain whatever delimiter you use it will still fail ... should be some better way.